# How can I fetch data from a Firestore reference?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have the `chat` collection that has the following fields: `hasUnreadMessage` as a Bool, `isActive` as a Bool, `person` as a reference to
`person` collection, `messages` as an array of references to `message` collection.

Here are some screenshots
[image: chat]
[image: person]
[image: message]

I want to create a function to fetch all the messages but for example in the person reference when I print directly the call of the `imgString` or `name` it's correct, but when I add them to the `ChatModel` they are missing.
Here is the function that I created.

```
func fetchMessages() {
        db.collection("chat").getDocuments { snapshot, err in
            if let error = err {
                debugPrint("Error fething documents: \(error)")
            } else {
                guard let snap = snapshot else { return }
                for document in snap.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    var chatMessages: [Message] = []
                    var chat: ChatModel = ChatModel(person: Person(name: "", imgString: ""), messages: [], hasUnreadMessage: false, isActive: false)
                    let personRef = (document.get("person") as? DocumentReference ?? nil)?.getDocument(completion: { personSnapshot, personErr in
                        if let personError = personErr {
                            debugPrint("Error getting chat person: \(personError)")
                        } else {
                            guard let personSnap = personSnapshot else { return }
                            let personData = personSnap.data()
                            chat.person.imgString = personData?["imgString"] as? String ?? ""
                            chat.person.name = personData?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                        }
                    })
                    
                    let messages = document.get("messages") as? [DocumentReference] ?? []
                    for message in messages {
                        message.getDocument { messageSnapshot, messageErr in
                            if let messageError = messageErr {
                                debugPrint("Error getting message: \(messageError)")
                            } else {
                                guard let messageSnap = messageSnapshot else { return }
                                let messageData = messageSnap.data()
                                let date = messageData?["date"] as? String ?? ""
                                let text = messageData?["text"] as? String ?? ""
                                let type = messageData?["type"] as? String ?? ""
                                chatMessages.append(Message(text, type: type, date: date))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    chat.hasUnreadMessage = data["hasUnreadMessage"] as? Bool ?? false
                    chat.isActive = data["isActive"] as? Bool ?? false
                    chat.messages = chatMessages
                    
                    
                    self.chats.append(chat)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:
Here are the outputs. I saw that I called the `imgString` print before the `ChatModel` print and they appeared in the opposite order

```
BT_Tech.ChatModel(_id: FirebaseFirestoreSwift.DocumentID<Swift.String>(value: Optional("D195D8D8-F401-4C71-B571-4877E6574B68")), person: BT_Tech.Person(_id: FirebaseFirestoreSwift.DocumentID<Swift.String>(value: Optional("46768262-EB88-42B3-A9FF-4F9FF3A7B7F1")), name: "", imgString: ""), messages: [], hasUnreadMessage: true, isActive: true)

"imgString: girl1"
```

Here is the `ChatModel`

```
struct ChatModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var person: Person
    var messages: [Message]
    var hasUnreadMessage: Bool
    var isActive: Bool
}

struct Person: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var imgString: String
}

struct Message: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    var date: String
    var text: String
    var type: String
    
    init(_ text: String, type: String, date: String) {
        self.text = text
        self.type = type
        self.date = date
    }
    
    init(_ text: String, type: String) {
        self.init(text, type: type, date: "")
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show us where you `print directly the call of the imgString or name` and 
where you print the `ChatModel` that show the missing data. Also could you show the `ChatModel`

Comment: good start. Could you show us where (and how) in your code you print `imgString` and 
where you print the `ChatModel`.

Comment: "to fetch all the messages but for example in the person reference when I print directly the call of the imgString or name it's correct"  What does that mean?  What's the relationship between the person collection and the message collection?